# Method map() dose not work for a List in a Map

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I got a Map like this:

```
Map userInfo={
     'name':'jack',
     'age':30,
     'interests':[
       {'name':'swimming','level':1},{'name':'running','level':2},
     ]
    }
```

and now I wanna use method map() to convert interests to a list of Widgets, if I use userInfo['interests'] below, it will not work:

```
userInfo['interests'].map((item){return new Text(item['name'])}).toList() //not work
```

but, if save userInfo['interests'] in a variable first, it works:

```
List tmpVariable=userInfo['inetrests'];
tmpVariable.map((item){return new Text(item['name'])}).toList()  //this works
```

so the question is that if I got a structure like above, can I map it directly? Or what's best way to deal with that? Use variable is not so good I think. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(userInfo['interests'] as List).map((item){return new Text(item['name'])}).toList()
```

Comment: It works, thanks so much! Still, I'm curious about that, Is userInfo['interests'] not a real List? (Forgive my offence)

Comment: No, it's a Map by default